# map_dbl with list column gives Error: Result 1 must be a single double, not a double vector of length

Tags: r, purrr

```
diamonds %>% 
  mutate(log_price = log(price)) %>% 
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(scale_log = map_dbl(data, ~.x$log_price %>% scale %>% as.vector))
```

Desired outcome is a new variable scale_log that is just a vector for each row of the data frame. The code above gives:

> Error: Result 1 must be a single double, not a double vector of length 1610

It works if I just use regular map:

```
x <- diamonds %>% 
  mutate(log_price = log(price)) %>% 
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(scale_log = map(data, ~.x$log_price %>% scale %>% as.vector))
```

But when I do this x$scale_log is a list whereas I wanted it to be just a vector:

```
x %>% glimpse
Rows: 5
Columns: 3
Groups: cut [5]
$ cut       <ord> Ideal, Premium, Good, Very Good, Fair
$ data      <list> [<tbl_df[21551 x 11]>, <tbl_df[13791 x 11]>, <tbl_df[4906 x 11]>, <tbl_df[12082 x 11]>, <tbl_df[1610 x 11]>]
$ scale_log <list> [<-1.8668994653, -1.8245259872, -1.8127394789, -1.8010892338, -1.6532201679, -1.6532201679, -1.6532201679, -1.6507226822, -1.6507226822, -1…
```

How can I use map_dbl to get my desired outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't `nest` nor use any version of `map`, you can use  `group_by` + `mutate` combination.

```
library(dplyr)

diamonds %>% 
  mutate(log_price = log(price)) %>% 
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  mutate(scale_log = as.numeric(scale(log_price)))
```

---

The issue with `map_dbl` approach is :

```
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

diamonds %>% 
 mutate(log_price = log(price)) %>% 
 group_by(cut) %>% 
 nest()

# cut       data                  
#  <ord>     <list>                
#1 Ideal     <tibble [21,551 × 10]>
#2 Premium   <tibble [13,791 × 10]>
#3 Good      <tibble [4,906 × 10]> 
#4 Very Good <tibble [12,082 × 10]>
#5 Fair      <tibble [1,610 × 10]>
```

This is a 5 row-dataframe, when you use `map_dbl` it returns you values which is same as `nrow(diamonds)` i.e  53940. `mutate` expects output to be of same number of rows i.e 5, hence there is an error.

You can solve this by keeping the data in a list using `map` and then `unnest`.

```
diamonds %>% 
  mutate(log_price = log(price)) %>% 
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  nest() %>%
  summarise(scale_log = map(data, ~.x$log_price %>% scale %>% as.vector)) %>%
  unnest(scale_log)
```

Comment: That's interesting syntax, group by followed by mutate as opposed to followed by summarise. If I read it correctly, it's telling r to scale(log_price) within each group in the group by only, as opposed to across the entire data frame?

Comment: Yes, `scale(log_price)` is referring to `log_price` values in each group.